# Proof of the arc length parametrization is $1$

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb R^n$ be a regular curve.

Let $p:[a,b] \to [0, p(b)]$ be the map $p(t) = \int_{a}^t \|\gamma' (s) \|ds$. Then $p^{-1}: [0,p(b)] \to [a,b]$.

I tried to show that $\|\gamma'(p^{-1}(s))\| = 1$ (for all $s\in[a,b]$). Can you check my work please? Proof is:

By definitions, if $s=p(t)$ then $p'(t) = \|\gamma' (t) \|$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and

$\gamma'(p^{-1}(s)) = {d \over ds}\gamma(p^{-1}(s)) = {d p^{-1} (s) \over ds } {d \gamma(p^{-1}) \over d p^{-1}} = {1 \over p' (p^{-1} (s))} {d \gamma (p^{-1}) \over dp^{-1}}$

therefore 
$$\|\gamma'(p^{-1}(s))\| =  {1 \over \| p' (p^{-1} (s))\|} \left \| {d \gamma (p^{-1})  \over  dp^{-1} } \right \|= {1 \over  \| p' (p^{-1} (p(t)))\| } \|\gamma' (t)\|= {\|\gamma'(t)\| \over \|p'(t)\|}= {\|\gamma' (t)\| \over \|\|\gamma' (t)\|\|}1$$.

Comment: You don't have to do the substitution $s = p(t)$, since directly $p'(p^{-1}(s)) = \|\gamma'(p^{-1}(t))\|$, which is the second term in your calculations.